# SQL - Return records with highest version for each quotation ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table with three columns like below

```
CREATE TABLE QUOTATIONS 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    VERSION INT NOT NULL,
    PRICE FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

In addition to this, lets say that the table consists of the follow records:

```
ID  |  VERSION  |  PRICE
----+-----------+--------
1   |     1     |   50
1   |     2     |   40
1   |     3     |   30
2   |     1     |   100
2   |     2     |   80
3   |     1     |   50
```

Is there any single SQL query that can be run and return the rows of all quotations with the highest version only?

The results should be like follow:

```
ID  |  VERSION  |  PRICE
----+-----------+--------
1   |     3     |   30
2   |     2     |   80
3   |     1     |   50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this method which uses no subqueries:

```
select top (1) with ties q.*
from quotations q
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc);
```

Basically, the `row_number()` assigns "1" to the highest version for each `id`.  The `top (1) with ties` returns all the `1`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,version,price
FROM tableName t
     JOIN (SELECT id,MAX(version) AS version 
           FROM tableName
           GROUP BY id) AS q1 ON q1.id = t.id AND q1.version = t.version
```